# Assigning value to combobox in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I have populated a combobox in a datagridview. This works perfect. My issue is, how do i assign a certain value to the combobox in a datagridview? I want the user to be able to load the form and have a certain value already displayed with the option to choose items that have been added to the combobox.

```
For Each row In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
        row.Height = 40
        row.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
        Dim dgvcombo As DataGridViewComboBoxCell
        dgvcombo = row.Cells(2)
        row.Cells(0).Value = tasknum
        row.Cells(1).Value = GetScalarData("SELECT duedate FROM task WHERE capaID = '" & CAPAid & "' AND task = '" & tasknum & "'")
        For i = 0 To x.Count - 1
            dgvcombo.Items.Add(x(i))
        Next

        tasknum = tasknum + 1
    Next row
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Show how you tried to set a value. [Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753536/how-to-add-items-in-the-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-of-datagridview-during-runtim)

Comment: row.Cells(2).Value = "Hello".....This is what i tried and received an error.  The error is "DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid".

Comment: Did you set it to be a value that existed in the list of items? If not you will get errors. In this case "Hello" would have to be one of the combobox items.